# I am working on TODO, I want the bin image and list style image to have space in between but when i apply flex property on "list" the image dissapear

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want the **List-Style-Image** to be Apppear while using **"flex"** and have space between **"bin"** image and **List-Style-Image** . I dont know why every time i apply the flex-property on "Li" the image dissapear's

```
let input = document.querySelector("#textFeild");
let button = document.querySelector("#button"); 
let toDoContainer = document.querySelector("#toDoContainer");
let ul = toDoContainer.querySelector("ul");


// Adding Event on Button 
button.addEventListener("click", function(){
  let li = document.createElement('li');
  li.style.listStyleImage = "url('assets/icons/checkbox.png')";  
  li.style.display = "list-item";
  li.innerText = input.value;
  li.style.fontSize = "30px";
  li.style.borderBottom = "1px solid #f2f1f1";
  li.style.padding = "20px";
  li.style.display = "flex";   //problem is here 
  li.style.justifyContent = "space-between";  
  ul.appendChild(li);
  let bin = document.createElement("IMG");
  bin.setAttribute("src", "assets/icons/bin.png");
  bin.setAttribute("width", "30");
  bin.style.marginLeft = "auto";
  li.appendChild(bin);
  input.value = "";  //It will Clear the Feild for next Value.

  //We write Event-listner on Paragrahs (Nested) Here Because of "let" Block-Scope.
  li.addEventListener("click", function(){
    li.style.textDecoration = "line-through";
    li.style.listStyleImage = "url('assets/icons/checkmark.png')"; 
  })
  bin.addEventListener("click", function(){
    ul.removeChild(li);
  })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You are setting `li.style.display = "list-item";` and then rewriting it to `flex`. [Property listStyleImage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/list-style-image) is for elements with `display: list-item`